# how to make sure single guava service manager instance per jvm?

Tags: java, guava, servicemanager

Singleton pattern allows to contain one instance per application thread.

How can I make sure only single instance of guava Service Manager  is running per JVM ?  So when ever it launches a new seperate entry java thread can check  whether the service manager is running.

Comment: Pls state any comments to improve the question ?

Comment: I'm not very sure what's the problem, my answer may help or not.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that simply not creating multiple instances wouldn't work? Implement a `ServiceManagerProvider` as a singleton and use only `serviceManagerProvider.get()` for accessing the Service Manager.

---

Consider using Dependency Injection instead of the singleton (anti-)pattern:

```
@Singleton
public class ServiceManagerProvider implements Provider<ServiceManager> {
    private final ServiceManager serviceManager = ...

    @Overrride
    public ServiceManager get() {
        return serviceManager;
    }
}
```

Here, you get a single instance per injector, which is exactly what you (should) want.